# PHP - flatten array with only one element

Tags: php, arrays

How can I flatten array with only one item (I want to avoid using **$array[0]['name']**? Array is looking like this:

```
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'project_id' => string '28' 
      'project_name' => string 'Test User'
```

Comment: Use `array_pop($your_array);`

Comment: That works :). Thanks :).

Comment: Note : It disturbs the original array, and you can never use previous array again after doing array_pop.

Comment: That is fine. I need to user the array several times throughout the page, and it is a bit cleaner to use $array['project_name'] then $array[0]['project_name'];

Answer (score 2):

use `current`

```
current($arr)
```

it would return false, if the array has no items

see: http://php.net/manual/en/function.current.php

Answer (score -1):

Simply create a new variable

```
$flatArray = $arr[0];
$flatArray['name'];
```

Or use `array_pop`

```
$flatArray = array_pop($arr);
```

Comment: *I want to avoid using $array[0]['name']*

Comment: You are not using `$array[0]['name'], and it does not involve a function call.

Comment: And it does not modify the original array if it is ever needed again.